# How can I adjust 'horizontal space constraints' programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS, is there anyway I can adjust 'horizontal space constraints' programmatically (e.g. change from 20 to 0) in my code after the xib is loaded?

In my xib file, when I view it in Xcode, I have a 'Horizontal space constraints - (20) - Cell - View'.  How can I reference that in my code?
How to change the 'Constant' from 20 to 0?

Comment: You can create an @IBOutlet in code and point that to constraint in Interface Builder. Once you have constraint (say myConstraint), set "myConstraint.constant = 0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an `IBOutlet` for the constraint, just like you would for a `UILabel`, `UIButton`, etc. In your code, when you want to adjust the constraint, change its `constant` property. You can also animate it if you want using `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration` class method. In the block, you'd do this:

```
//Inside animation block
myHorizontalConstraint.constant = 0;
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```